# Перенаправление портов Apache

Tags: apache

Что прописать в конфигурации Apache, чтоб происходило перенаправление с 445 на 80?

Comment: Уточните, что именно вы хотите  получить.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно такое:

`RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PORT}" "^445$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*) "http://%{HTTP_HOST}:80/$1" [L,R,NE]`